# "Property does not exist in type"

Tags: javascript, html, angular, typescript

I've recently started studying Angular and I'm currently working on an assignment, which is about making a form with radius inputs. After doing the form, I'm working now on checking if the answers are correct, but I'm getting two errors when doing this check. What I'm trying to do is, to delete from the array all incorrect answers (value = 0).

This is the HTML file:

```
 <form>
  <div class="container" *ngFor = "let question of questions">
    <h4>{{question.question}}</h4>
    <label class="radio" *ngFor="let alternative of question.alternatives">
      <input class="subtotal" type="radio" name="{{question.question}}" value="{{alternative.value}}"> {{alternative.answer}}
    </label>
  </div>
</form>
```

This is the Typescript file:

```
  sumValue(){
    let radius = document.querySelectorAll(".subtotal:checked");
    if(radius.length == 11){
      console.log(radius);
      for (let index = 0; index < radius.length; index++) {
        console.log(radius[index].value);
        if(radius[index].value == 0){
          radius.splice(index, 1);
        }
      }
    } else {
      console.log('error');
    }
  }
```

On the "console.log(radius[index].value);" I get the following error:

```
[ts] Property 'value' does not exist on type 'Element'.
```

And on "radius.splice(index, 1);" I get:

```
[ts] Property 'splice' does not exist on type 'NodeListOf<Element'.
```

[I still haven't reputation to post images yet, but this is the view on VSCode](https://i.stack.imgur.com/FHWBu.png)
I appreciate any help and explanations on other ways to solve my problem which is, how to leave in the array only the answers that are correct. Thank you!

Comment: check if the value property exists before using it directly

Comment: The console.log(radius[index].value) shows the values on the console, but it says they don't exist. How do I check if it exists or declare it? Thank you

Comment: check if the value exists for every items. It might happen that value exists for some item and doesn't for other. Then it will throw error. So check it like that if (radius[index] && radius[index].value){......}

Comment: And btw, you can't use splice in Nodelist. querySelectorAll returns a Nodelist which is diff than array. You can't use splice(), push(), join(), indexOf(), and many other methods on Nodelist.

Comment: Oh I see, damn I don't know how to get the values from the arrays anymore then.

Comment: you can convert it to an array tho. use foreach and push every item in an actual empty array. Then Nodelist will be be converted into an array with all the methods available. If you using Ecmascript 6 then you can do it with one liner: var arr = Array.from(radius);

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What you are seeing is a type error.

When calling `document.querySelectorAll`, it returns a `NodeList<Element>` because it doesn't know that the matched elements are going to be `<input/>`s. [What it returns instead is the base type for all elements](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Element), which is a super class of `<input/>`.

The second issue is that `NodeList` does not have a `splice` method.

To fix the first issue, you can give the `radius` variable a type:

```
let radius: NodeList<HTMLInputElement> = document.querySelectorAll(".subtotal:checked");
```

However, your use of HTML elements in the component is not the "correct" angular way. You do not want to access HTML elements directly in your angular component - you want to maintain separation between your page and the logic behind it. Instead, you can use Angular's binding system. More specifically, `ngModel`:

```
 <form>
  <div class="container" *ngFor = "let question of questions">
    <h4>{{question.question}}</h4>
    <label class="radio" *ngFor="let alternative of question.alternatives">
      <input class="subtotal" type="radio" [attr.name]="question.question" [value]="alternative.value" [(ngModel)]="question.answer"> {{alternative.answer}}
    </label>
  </div>
</form>
```

Now, whenever the user edits the input, the `question.answer` property gets updated automatically. In your component, you can iterate over the structure to remove invalid alternatives:

```
sumValue(){

    this.questions.forEach(question => {
        question.alternatives = question.alternatives.filter(a => a.value != 0);
    });

}
```

This code uses [the filter method of an array](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/filter) to create an array of just the elements with values that are not equal to zero. We can then use that to replace the old `alternatives` array. Angular will handle rendering the page to reflect the changes in data.

[You can read more about ngModel here.](https://angular.io/api/forms/NgModel)

[You can also read more about how to use radio buttons with angular here](https://angular.io/api/forms/RadioControlValueAccessor).

Comment: Thanks! This solved the compilation problem, but has led me to another one. The console now logs "Error: If ngModel is used within a form tag, either the name attribute must be set or the form
      control must be defined as 'standalone' in ngModelOptions.". I tried setting a name to it, or using the [ngModelOptions]="{standalone: true}", when I do this the compilation happens without errors, but when I choose one option, it marks the last wrong answer in all 10 questions, or the right answer in all of them if the first one chosen is the correct one. I really appreciate your help!

Comment: I removed the form tag as I wasn't using any of it's properties and changed it to a div. Now I don't get the console error, but the one where all wrong or all right options persist. Any ideas on why this is happening and how to solve it?

Comment: If you made and shared a Plunkr, I could help get it working. Here is an empty Angular Plunk: https://plnkr.co/edit/tpl:AvJOMERrnz94ekVua0u5 When you have a form element in the page, angular requires it has a name so it can track and validate the input. Can you try name="{{question.question}}" instead?