# Changing style of getElementsByClassName gives compile error

Tags: javascript, html, css, typescript, angular5

I am trying to change the style of all of the elements which I received by calling the method getElementsByClassName. The thing is that it does work when it has compiled before (I commented these rows out to let it compile), it just says the error in the cmd. After it compiled I just set the lines back to normal, they keep giving errors but are working in the browser. Any thoughts on this weird behavior?

[image]

[image]

When commented out:

[image]

When not commented and giving errors:

[image]

Comment: can u use jquery?

Comment: I can use jquery, but I prefer not to do so. If i do not find any solution regarding this I will use the jquery notation

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I think the problem is with TypeScript. You should try this workaround

```
var texts = document.getElementsByClassName("section_text") as HTMLCollectionOf<HTMLElement>;
```

Comment: I sadly cannot use the HTMLElement tag, since the collection is a 
<HTMLCollectionOf<Element>>. It can be a problem of typescript ofcourse.

Comment: This did it, thank you! It now compiles without giving any errors.

Answer (score 0):

you can simply `addClass()`:
**CSS**

```
.newStyle{
    width:100%;
    float:left;
}
```

**Use Jquery**

```
$('.section_text input').addClass('newStyle');
```

**Use Javascript**

```
document.querySelector('.section_text input').classList.add('newStyle';
```

Comment: here is how to add class using js:https://www.w3schools.com/howto/howto_js_add_class.asp

Answer (score 0):

I had a similar issue when trying to pull off something with angular. The problem is that the `getElementsByClassName` returns a nodelist, not a normal array, so you can't access properties like you're trying to. [You can read more in about it in this answer.](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49786681/property-does-not-exist-in-type)

Answer (score 0):

`getElementsByClassName` returns a nodelist. Access properties directly.

```
let hiddenLocales = document.getElementsByClassName('localeMatch') as HTMLCollectionOf<HTMLElement>;
let hideParentNode = hiddenLocales[0].parentElement;
hideParentNode?.classList.add('newStyle');
```

[image]